# How to get ScrollViews' total amount in scrollView?

Tags: android, android-scrollview

Before explain, **ScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount() doesn't work properly.**
When I use `ScrollView.getMaxScrollAmount()`, It returns 865 and doesn't work properly. I put in 1mb text in ScrollView, and Its true Y Value is about 760000.

I get the true Value to use `ScrollView.getScrollY() - ScrollView.getChildAt(0).getHeight()`.

Is there any person who knows why this method return doesn't properly value?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `scrollview` for text. make `textview` scrollable

```
android:maxLines = "IntegerValue"
android:scrollbars = "vertical"
```

now in your activity

```
textview.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

Hope it will help you!!